# Which Apache module is required by Drupal system

Tags: 6

Could anyone advise which Apache module is required by Drupal system?

Comment: Found a answer here:
http://www.sitebuddy.com/apache/apache_required_modules_minimum_modules_to_run_a_drupal_site_php_mysql

Answer (score 2):

The most common enabled module (or installed if not available) is mod_rewrite which helps your site have nice and clean urls. But even this isn't really required ... you can live without it but your site won't have nice links instead they will look like : www.example.com?q=node/12345. If PHP is working than that means that you have the necessary config to run Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you really only need (these are PHP extensions):
mbstring
curl
gd
mysql
mcrypt
jpeg
png
xml

...but not completely sure. my configuration above suits me fine. not sure if it can be of any help. If you using php as a module in apache, you can eliminate the fastcgi part.

Comment: The first items you have listed are PHP extensions, not Apache extensions, correct?

Comment: yes, that's right